# If conditions while passing paramters to child component in aura

Tags: lightning-aura-components, aura, aura-attribute, lightning-components, aura-if

I am trying to pass a value from parent to child component in the following manner

```
<c:contactSelect accountId="{!IF(v.proposal.CurrencyIsoCode != 'US' && v.proposal.BillingCountry__c != 'US' && v.proposal.ResellerPartner__c != null, v.pubQuoteDocuSign.proposal.ResellerPartner__c, v.proposal.Proposal__Account__c)}"/>
```

However, when I try to save the above piece of code it gives me the following error

Failed to save pubQuoteDocuSignComponent.cmp: c:pubQuoteDocuSignComponent:44,260: ParseError at [row,col]:[45,260] Message: The entity name must immediately follow the '&' in the entity reference.: Source

Is this not the correct syntax?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because these components are XML, you need to escape the `&` character (this character is used to render unprintable characters, etc). You escape ampersand with `&amp;`, as in:

```
<c:contactSelect accountId="{!if(v.proposal.CurrencyIsoCode != 'US' &amp;&amp; v.proposal.BillingCountry__c != 'US' &amp;&amp; v.proposal.ResellerPartner__c != null, v.pubQuoteDocuSign.proposal.ResellerPartner__c, v.proposal.Proposal__Account__c)}"/>
```

This is called out in the [documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/expr_operators.htm).

It's worth noting that the and() function is preferred for this reason.

```
<c:contactSelect accountId="{!if(and(and(v.proposal.CurrencyIsoCode != 'US',v.proposal.BillingCountry__c != 'US'), v.proposal.ResellerPartner__c != null), v.pubQuoteDocuSign.proposal.ResellerPartner__c, v.proposal.Proposal__Account__c)}"/>
```

`and()` only works with two operators, so you have to nest them if you need more than two.

Finally, note that these operators are case sensitive. You can't use `IF` instead of `if`.

Comment: Thanks a ton. That was very helpful. I ultimately ended uo using the second approach that you provided.